# GCC Fatal Error

Tags: programming, gcc, c

everyone

Here's my problem; So, I'm new to Ubuntu and programming and I just wanted to start with C. I created the classic "hello.c" file

```
#include <stdio.h>   
main ()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Then I typed within the terminal:

```
cd /Desktop
```

Because the file is located in Desktop

And then I typed

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

But here come the troubles, it suddenly appeared a problem that says:

```
gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: I seem to recall gcc used to just say "no input files"  That seems  less confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Desktop is not located at `/Desktop` rather it is located at `~/Desktop`.
Thus execute these commands.

1. `cd ~/Desktop`  (for changing directory to Desktop)
2. `gcc hello.c -o hello` (for compiling C program)
3. Then execute your application by `./hello` , if it shows any error change its permissions with `chmod +x hello`

Comment: `gcc` gives it `+x` by default, I thought... at least in 14.04 and later.

Answer (score 3):

> Then I typed within the terminal: `cd /Desktop`

`/Desktop` is not the path to your desktop. `/Desktop` is the path to a directory "`Desktop`" in `/` (your `root` directory). `/home/<username>/Desktop` or, shortened, `~/Desktop` is the path to your desktop.

So first change your terminal's working directory to your desktop's path:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Then compile the file again:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```